# Advice needed for REST infrastructure design

Tags: api, rest, api-design

This one is not about a technical issue but more about how to design the communication between several APIs. Let's say there are only these **4 components** when looking from an infrastructure point (microservice arhitecture)

- Collector  -> grabs data from an external source 1, does some minor remapping and that's it.
- Collector -> grabs data from an external source 2, does some minor    remapping and that's it.
- Aggregator -> stores data from collector APIs, does moderate    remapping of data to make it structured how I want it.
- Scheduler -> is responsible for the periodical triggering of getting    data from external sources.

*Ideas I came up with:*

**Approach 1**

- Scheduler calls Aggreagators endpoint. The aggregator then makes an
  HTTP call to the collector, receives the response and stores in the
  database.

**Approach 2**

- Scheduler calls the collector, get's the data and then makes another
  call to the aggregator component to store the data.

**Approach 3**

- Scheduler calls the collector and sends the callback url for the
  aggregator (or the aggregator URL is already known to the collector
  component), the collector grabs the data from an external source and
  then calls the aggregator component.

My realizations so far:

**Approach 1:**

> Endpoints on the aggregator are not RESTful. Imagine you wanna get all football games data for a specific country in the year 2020. You would pass the country and year as query parameters to a POST endpoint on the aggregator component but that's not the actual data you're gonna end up with in your database. This is a simple approach but I don't like that that the endpoints on the aggregator component are not transparent about what are they doing.

**Approach 2:**

> This approach allows proper RESTful API design but it does require the scheduler to also act as a proxy. The scheduler is not gonna serialize and then deserialize the data. It's just going to get the data from the collector's GET endpoint and forward it to the aggregator's POST endpoint, but it adds additional complexity to this component.

**Approach 3:**

> Allow for proper RESTful API design, but I don't like that the logic of how actually the data gets into the aggregator (and therefore the database) is hidden in the collectors component. Also, with every new collector, the same "logic" would be duplicated.

So far, Approach 2 seems to make the most sense to me despite making the component a *half-scheduler* and a *half-proxy*. Additionally, I could introduce a new proxy component. Maybe the "proxy" is not the best wording but you get the point.

> It would get called by a scheduler and then it would grab the data from the collector and forward it to the aggregator but adding this component seems to bring more complexity to the whole system and I'm not sure it's going to bring any real value.

I'm open to other approaches, suggestions, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

I like your approach 2 better but overall my views:

All the operations look pretty asynchronous, since the collectors could take a lot
of time and the aggregator is pretty much dependent on it.

The aggregator should know about the collectors since between systems (lets say aggregator and collector) there should be a contract which can be upheld by a CDC (consumer driven contract test) so the consumer knows what and how producer is producing.

Approach 1
Scheduler can directly call the aggregator providing the URLs for the collectors (can store in scheduler, or have aggregator know about it, preferably latter as scheduler will only schedule stuff). But here aggregator needs to wait for collectors to respond as well, hence waiting part (which is what scheduler does best), can be avoided. Also chaining HTTP call is probably not a good idea. Bad design. For multiple API call internally, we use async design like Event Driven Architecture.

Approach 2
Scheduler calls the collectors to start collecting. Once finished, let scheduler know. The scheduler then asks aggregators to start operation.
a. The scheduler should not direct information from collector to aggregator but aggregator can directly do a API call to fetch data from collector DIRECTLY.

a. Also, you could have collector APIs sending data to aggregator async in a message bus and aggregator processing incoming data (or storing a local copy and work on it later). This makes systems more de-coupled. So scheduler only calls collectors to start.

c. If collectors goes down, the aggregator can still respond with stale data.

Approach 3
sounds consumer (collector) knowing how to call producer (aggregator) which I think is not the responsibility of producer which should not know about consumer, also it is leaking resource info to producer.

Comment: I like the idea of having a message bus but at this current stage of the project, this implementation is not an option.

In the Approach 2, I would need to create some kind of cache/buffer where the collector would store the data that it has processed, and then it would be cleared up when the aggregator pulls it. I would still need to send some kind of response to the scheduler to let it know the job is done and that the aggregator can now fetch data. Since I'm not dealing with real-time data and endpoints don't rely on each other, I don't think async would bring any value. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, message bus would be overkill since it is not real time. The collector could just respond back with 200 OK, process executed, or just a ping is enough for scheduler. And later aggregator can do a fetch data when scheduler clears it to do so (i.e. check if collector job is done). Since it is not real-time, you could time the batch jobs. Batch job or scheduled calls are in a way async.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think I found the best solution :)

Always love some healthy discussions like these ones